# How to exact frames from the mp4 which has different orientation(different frame size, recorded from phone) in the video?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I use [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy) record an video on Android phone.

`scrcpy -r record.mp4`

The video changed the orientation when recording. It has different frame size.

For example, the video is 1920x720 at begin, after 30s, the video has changed the orientation, frame size is 720x1920.

How can I exact all the frames and keep the frame size?

I use ffmpeg exact the frame, but I got all frames witch size 1920x720, and the frame has been stretched.

`ffmpeg -i record.mp4 -y -r 30 out/output-%05d.jpeg`